# Android studio: Use JARS from other Project

Tags: android, import, jar, aar

My app uses several JARS, AAR's and JNI Libs from another (big) Android Studio Project, that has like 20 modules, some of them JAR's, and some of them AAR's.

At the moment I'm manually copying all stuff into the App project "libs/" folder, and also importing the AAR's as new modules.

Is there an easier way to do it? Both projects are local on my development machine, but are **separate** Android Studio projects. I'd like to keep them this way, as the big library project is an active GitHub project that I frequently update.

Ideally I'd like to reference the JARS and AAR's from the other project without the need to copy them.

Comment: You can reference relative paths to projects using Gradle

Answer (score 1):

Add the module into your project as project library. In the build.gradle file of your application add following dependencies with the library location. For example you want to add library `lib1` from your library project `mylibproject` with the path `libproject\lib1`,

```
dependencies {
     ...
     compile project(':mylibproject:lib1')
 }
```

Do it for the selective libraries you want to include. It will work

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating symbolic links between the jar files and your project.

On Linux or Mac it's:

ln -s source dest

Answer (score 0):

try

```
project
 | build.gradle
 | settings.gradle
 + app/
    | build.gradle
 + mylib1/
    | build.gradle
 + mylib2/
    | build.gradle
```

in **project/setting.gradle** add:

default:

```
include ':app'
```

modified:

```
include ':app', ':mylib1', ':mylib2'
```

and in **project/app/build.gradle** add:

```
compile project(':mylib1')
compile project(':mylib2')
```

More info: [Creating-a-Library-Project](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-Library-Project)